# Good way to apply multiple Context with React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Currently, 
I have CategoryContext to manage Category state, 
ModalContext to manage Modal state.

```
<Layout>
   <ModalContext.Provider>
   <Route>
       <CategoryContext.Provider />
           <CategoryPage />
   </Route>
   <ModalContext.Provider />
</Layout>
```

I'm just move from redux to react-hook to manage state. Then I'm not sure my solution is good or not? I'm happy to get more idea from social :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by move from redux to hook since you can use redux with [hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks). I think you meant you replaced redux with context.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to use everything by hooks. Currently I'm using { useContext, useReducer } to simulate redux. But my question focus on the way we manage multiple context. Which way can make the app is more extendable when I have more Contexts

Comment: This probably isn't a good use of context. The idea of context is to allow multiple components access to that state, but if you're only setting up context for one component you're better off using `useState` or `useReducer` within the component instead. On the other hand, if you want the state in the category context to be available to loads of other components you might be better off with a single app context to contain both modal and category states, and dispatching to that instead.

Comment: Nice catch @Andy. In my example I just show a small case. In react-hook document they write: "A component calling useContext will always re-render when the context value changes. If re-rendering the component is expensive, you can optimize it by using memoization." Then I don't want to use only one context. Example If I have Modal Context, Customer Context and I put all of them in App Context then if some component just need use Customer Context will be effected when Modal Context state changed. Split Context is Preferred in https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156#issuecomment-474590693

Comment: If you want to make your own homebrew redux with react-redux then maybe [this](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/homebrew-redux) can give you some ideas. Code for store, provider and hooks is [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/homebrew-redux/blob/master/store/index.js) I would not advice to use it in a production app but more as a learning experience. If you do use your homebrew then it would be best to make the API similar so you can always replace the homebrew with redux and react-redux.

Comment: To optimize redux applications you can memoize mapStateToProps (the hooks version is useSelector) and make presentational components pure components by using React.memo or call them with useMemo from your container. Example of react-redux hooks container is [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/homebrew-redux/blob/master/example/src/Counter/Container.js#L20-L28) it uses the homebrew but has the same API as react-redux hooks.

Comment: Yes thanks @HMR. I haven't use Memo. But I will try it thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple context Providers that wrap components you wish to use context in. However in your case you aren't wrapping the component with provider but just rendering it in case of `CategoryContext`

```
<Layout>
   <ModalContext.Provider>
   <Route>
       <CategoryContext.Provider >
           <CategoryPage />
       </CategoryContext.Provider >
   </Route>
   <ModalContext.Provider />
</Layout>
```

Comment: Yes I'm putting my Category Component inside 2 Context.Provider then I will useContext inside my Component. In Category Component I can get state from Modal and Category context. But I'm not sure this is a good way if I have more Context later

Comment: @NghiNguyen You can have as many context as you need and localize those to the common parent of the components that need that context value. Its not necessary to  have one context only

Comment: I'm thinking about manage by combine multiple Contexts. Now I got ModalContext that one will be used global. But maybe in future I will have SessionContext it will be applied to whole app also. I don't want to use many nested level in App. Do you have any solution for this case ?

Comment: The solution in such cases is either to combine multiple contexts into one which are applicable to the entire app or have a wrapper that manages and renders  multiple contexts. However I would still suggest you to have multiple contexts as you can localize logic

Comment: Sound Great ! I haven't think about logic. Could you give me an example ? Thanks :)

Comment: Consider for example scenarios you have a context provider for  handling keyboard shortcuts and other for handling userData. Both are separate logics and its better if they are kept apart and not mixed in a single file.

Comment: I think I need a Global Context to contains something will be shared for whole app. Example like Modal, Session, ...  and Product Context it relates to Product, Category, ... it just uses in Product Section.